# Using Object type parameters as method arguments?

Tags: java, methods, arguments

The following shows a Main method that must print an average grade from a Student Object. It has a type Student and SID in the method call so it can print out the average grade of an simple Array of three grades. What would the parameter be for a Student type?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    add("101", "Jacob", "Elderinsky", "J.Elder@gmail.com",25, 89, 99.0, 65.0);
    add("201", "Trever", "Riley-Thomas", "stay umble@class.com", 32, 66.0, 84.0, 96.0);
    add("301", "Alexis", "Salkolnikov", "allsalk@outlook.com", 15, 99.0, 100.0, 100.0);
    add("401", "Regina", "Washington", "talktothis@wgu.edu", 19, 92, 96, 92);
    add("501", "Ryan", "Raskolnikov", "agawro1@my.wgu.edu", 28, 99.0, 100.0, 94.0);

    print_all();
    print_invalid_emails();
    printAverageGrade();// <-------------- Parameter???
    remove("3");
    remove("3");
```

The compiler is telling me the SID (Student ID) is invalid when I try using String or integer input.

```
public static void printAverageGrade(Student SID) {
    double[] grades = SID.getGrades();
    System.out.println(SID.getSID() + "\t" + (grades[0] + grades[1] + grades[2]) / 3.0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printAverageGrade(Student SID)
```

This method accepts only Student object as per the definition -- that is why you cannot pass either String or Integer to this method.

Comment: Understandable. But then how do I pass the Student into the method to return an average grade?  See the top of main, I've added 5 students, and this method requires me to print the average grade (last three inputs of the 5 students)